# What does 'Ox' mean

Tags: unicode, ascii

[image]

I'm trying to get a better understanding of ASCII and unicode so I'm watching a talk from 2012 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc. In this Ned Batcheldor puts up a slide in the screenshot. Could someone explain what the axes mean. I assume that with an 8-bit byte that you could have up to 256 charachters encoded and each axis I guess uses 4 bytes, but I'm confused about the 'X' in the vertical axis. Would someone please explain further?

Comment: `x` is a placeholder; the hexadecimal numbers start with `0`, `1`, etc. and the column determines the second number.

Comment: Also, the table shown is not an ASCII table (only the first 127 characters are ASCII characters, as ASCII is a 7-bit encoding).

Comment: Replace the "X" with the appropriate header from the column, so `66` would be `f` and `75` would be `u`.

Comment: The slides for the talk are posted as part of the essay: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html. This is the [Windows CP1252 slide](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html#9).

Comment: Can I ask what the table represents then?

Comment: @user61629: it's the [Windows 1252 codepage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). Note how the table in that Wikipedia article uses `_` as the placeholder where Ned used `x`.

Comment: Sorry I know this is basic, but I've never really understood how the pieces fit together here

Comment: Part of the problem is that some people misuse the term "ASCII". Each character set has its own [official name](www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml#table-character-sets-1) and mapping table between characters and codepoints. Any similarity to ASCII is not all that relevant. Successful communication requires that the sender and receiver agree on the exact character set and encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x` is just a placeholder. The intersection of, for example, row `2x` and column 3 is codepoint `23` for whatever encoding this is.

Comment: Thank you, and I assume each axis is in units of 4 bits of a byte?

Comment: That is correct. `x` represents an arbitrary set of lower-order bits in a byte.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by lower-order ?